# How to properly uninstall a cuda toolkit which has not been installed by apt ?

Tags: uninstall, cuda, software-uninstall

I have troubles with my video and audio,for instance the display driver is disappearing without notice or the pavucontrol no longer provides a selection of the playback device. I believe it is because the cuda toolkit I have installed, not by apt but from a .run file.

It is the cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run file, I have not installed any further display drivers, though I downloaded  NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run (without installing it), but I do not know if I can use them together.

Now, I tried to uninstall the cuda-toolkit by:

```
cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run --uninstall
but it did not work, I only got an error message:
Logging to /tmp/cuda_install_6323.log
Installer must be in silent mode to use the toolkit, samples or driver command-line flags. Please also pass -silent to the installer.
```

I do not understand this, what is a silent mode and how to get into one?

Can I use apt-get purge even if I have not installed it by apt?

How to get rid off it?

Comment: apt/dpkg can only remove packages. If this isn't a deb package, then apt cannot help you.

Comment: According to the [CUDA toolkit documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#runfile-uninstallation), the recommended uninstall method is via a perl script that should be located in the bin directory of the toolkit. If you want to persevere with the .run file method, then what it seems to be telling you is to add `-silent` (or possibly `--silent`) to the command line options - I'd suggest trying `cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run --help` in the first instance.